# Assign a value?

Tags: vb.net

I have this

```
 Public Shared Sub Button9_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button9.Click
    Dim c As Client
    Dim Armor As Item = c.Inventory.GetItemInSlot(SlotNumber.Armor)
End Sub
```

And when I click the button, is crashes and "System.NullReferenceException" pops up , I've searched around and found out that it happens because c is used before it is assigned a value so I'd like to know, what would be the proper way to assign it a value?

Comment: What is `Client` datatype?

Comment: When I type just Client this pops up , ErrorBC30109 'Client' is a class type and cannot be used as an expression. So i assume its class type? Not sure if this is what your looking for tho, Im pretty new to all this. Not sure if its helpful anyhow but im using the dll from here https://code.google.com/archive/p/tibiaapi/downloads as a reference (v2.9.6)

Comment: Please update question with the following:  What is the context of this "Client"?, and what exactly are you trying to do with it via this button click?  Otherwise it is difficult to be able to tell you how to go about assigning a value as there's multiple ways depending on what it is and what you are doing with it.

Comment: Where is SlotNumber declared?

Answer (score 2):

try this:

instead of:

```
Public Shared Sub Button9_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button9.Click
    Dim c As New Client
    Dim Armor As Item = c.Inventory.GetItemInSlot(SlotNumber.Armor)
End Sub
```

try:

```
Public Shared Sub Button9_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button9.Click
    Dim c As New Client.Inventory
    Dim Armor As Item = c.Inventory.GetItemInSlot(SlotNumber.Armor)
End Sub
```

Comment: Still giving same problem.

Comment: instead of Dim c As New Client try Dim c As New Client.Inventory.